# SSL redirect fails on firefox and chrome, not edge

Tags: ssl, redirect

I have an SSL certificate from Certbot for "mysite". When I use FF or Chrome to go to mysite (with or without using the http:// prefix) I get to the non-SSL site. No redirect happens. But when I use Edge, my redirect works and I automatically get to https://mysite. In FF, when I get to the non-SSL site then I reload the page, I DO get to the SSL site. In Chrome, I cannot get to the SSL site, even if I enter the https://. The 2 sites are on the same **Windows** machine (using Apache server) with virtual hosts for ports 80 and 443. What am I missing?

```
Here are my virtual host directives:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin dforeman@stny.rr.com
    DocumentRoot "${djpath}"
    ServerName dforeman.homedns.org
    Redirect / https://dforeman.homedns.org
    ErrorLog "E:/logfiles/new-v80.log"
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost _default_:443>
# DO NOT replace _default_ above
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "E:/DJs Documents/apublic_html"
ServerName dforeman.homedns.org
ServerAdmin dforeman@stny.rr.com
ErrorLog "E:/logfiles/verror.log"
TransferLog "E:/logfiles/vhttp-access.log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:/fullchain.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/privkey.pem"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please add your apache virtual host configuration!

Comment: I have edited my original post to include my configuration. And here are my .htaccess directives. `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dforeman.homedns.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dforeman.homedns.org/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use in my https forwards:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin dforeman@stny.rr.com
    DocumentRoot "${djpath}"
    ServerName dforeman.homedns.org
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    ErrorLog "E:/logfiles/new-v80.log"
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: I don't use `.htaccess` files to achieve this.

Comment: Works great w/FF (THANKS).. When using Chrome the browser gets an error page, but then the error page is replaced with the HTTP NON- redirected page. If I put my cursor on the address and back up to the beginning, I see the https (in a light gray font), but there is an indicator saying insecure! So it appears that the suggested redirect is not working. With Edge, it says images are not secure.

Comment: The redirect itself is working. (Just opened your website via chrome android) I think the warning is related to the image sources you are displaying. Do you have something like `<img src="HTTP://someimagelocation">` in your code?

Comment: Here's an example of your index file causing these messages: 
`<img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px"
            src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
            alt="Valid CSS!">`

You can use the chrome developer tools for example to identify such problems. Just head to the sources tab ;)

Comment: Tanks all! You are correct. There were many http:// refs in the page. I have replaced them all with https:// and the redirect now works in all 3 browsers. I added a line of JS to show the value of "location.protocol" and it DOES display the "https" in the page title tab. Also found out that port #'s 80 and 443 display as empty for most browsers, so I couldn't display it.